# Java finally

Tags: java, исключения

Привет. Какая разница между использованием finally и помещением кода просто после блока try-catch?

То есть вместо

```
try {
    ...
}catch(Exception e){
    ...
}finally{
    <код>
}
```

Написать

```
try {
    ...
}catch(Exception e){
    ...
}
<код>
```

На ум приходит разве что наличие в блоках try и catch слова return, а в блоке finally действий, обязательных при завершении метода.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Блок `finally` будет выполнен даже если вы выполняете `return` в `try`-блоке, а также если исключение не будет поймано в блоке `catch` (например, если блок `catch` отсутствует, или тип исключения не совпадает с типом, обрабатываемым блоком `catch`). А также, если код `catch`-блока [сам выбросит исключение](http://ideone.com/YnEOTL). Во всех этих случаях код *после* блока `finally` выполнен не будет.

Кстати, код `finally` не будет выполнен, если код до него успеет вызвать `System.exit()` или произойдёт креш JVM (или процесс будет каким-либо внешним образом уничтожен).

Answer (score 4):

Код в блоке finally выполнится всегда, вне зависимости от того, будет вброшено исключение или нет. Если поместить код просто после блока try-catch, то в случае вброса исключения этот код не выполнится, так как из-за исключения прервется выполнение метода. Поправьте меня, если я не прав.

Поэтому, если нужно, например, закрыть поток или освободить ещё какие-то ресурсы в случае вброса исключения, нужно использовать блок finally

Comment: Разве прервётся выполнение метода? Разве не прервётся выполнение блока try?

Comment: Да, тут немного запамятовал, проигнорируется оставшаяся часть блока try.